# WPF DataGrid editable cells with Items put directively

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

So, I have a DataGrid, that I want to manipulate programmatically a lot.

```
string[] values = new string[something.Count];
for (int i = 0; i < somethingElse.Count; i++)
{
    if (condition)
        values[i] = Data[i].ToString();
    else
        values[i] = "";
}

var style = new System.Windows.Style(typeof(DataGridRowHeader));
style.Setters.Add(new Setter(DataGridRowHeader.ContentProperty, Data[0].ToString()));

MyGrid.Items.Add(new DataGridRow()
{
    HeaderStyle = style,
    Item = values
});
```

This I do in a loop and I am able to fill in my grid with all the data I need.
Later, I am able to access cells, edit them, take their values, whatever I want and need.
However, when user wants to use the grid as you would in MS Excel, the cells are not editable.

So I went the other way and created a :

```
ObservableCollection<ObservableCollection<string>> gridData = new ObservableCollection<ObservableCollection<string>>();

//*** ... *** the gridData is filled in the same way, you can imagine

MyGrid.ItemsSource = gridData;
```

This does fill in the data perfectly the same way, more than that, the data are now editable.
But my custom row headers disappeared.
I need them, also, I do not think I want to use binding for row header values.

Can the first approach be somehow modified to still be editable, but rows with data being filled the very same way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I eventually solved this combining both the abovementioned approaches.
First, I generate `ObservableCollection<ObservableCollection<string>> dataCollection`, fill it with data.

Next I generate an `ObservableCollection<DataGridRow> rowCollection` collection.

In my declarative part of the loop from the first approach, that you can see in the question, I do this

```
rowCollection.Add(new DataGridRow()
{
    HeaderStyle = style,
    Item = dataCollection[i]   //for the corresponding iteration element
});
```

This all ends up when setting

```
MyGrid.ItemsSource = rowCollection;
```

Till now (very little time of testing), this seems to be what I was looking for, hope it might help someone else aswell.